# How to plot the legend of a set of data with different color label in Mathplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a 1:1 plot in which the dot colour are different based on the condition (A-F), which comes from the same data frame column.

`df` is a data frame with data for every 1 min. `df60` is a data frame with data for every 1 hour.

```
plt.figure()
colors = {'A':'green', 'B':'aqua', 'C':'blue','D':'black','E':'yellow','F':'red'}

x = df['Method1'].loc['2020-01-01 00:00':'2020-01-15 23:59'].resample('h').mean()
y = df['Method2'].loc['2020-01-01 00:00':'2020-01-15 23:59'].resample('h').mean()

plt.scatter(x, y, c=df60['Method1'].loc['2020-01-01 00:00':'2020-01-15 23:59'].map(colors))
plt.show()
```

[image]

I have tried to plot the legend showing that which is A-F. However, since the data comes from the same column, it does not show what I am expecting. Are there any methods which help me to show the legend properly without breaking the column into several columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the legend manually by, for instance:

```
handles=[Line2D([0],[0],label=k,marker="o",markerfacecolor=v,markeredgecolor=v,linestyle="None") for k,v in colors.items()]

plt.legend(handles=handles)
```

This should produce: [image]

I hope this helps. Not really sure if there is a more elegant solution, though...

Comment: Thank you. The problem is solved. Btw, the code should add plt. before Line2D to work well.

Comment: Yes, you're right, thanks for pointing that. I didn't notice that detail because I worked with  ```from matplotlib.lines import Line2D``` when I did a quick test before answering.